# How to read a large JSON file as input for Azure Stream Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, stream-analytics

I am providing a JSON file of 5 MB size as input for Azure Stream Analytics and i am getting the below error.

"selected file 'filename' must be between 1 and 2097152 bytes"

Number of streaming units selected is 3. How to make Stream Analytics to read a large Json file as input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's limitation for the test of ASA job,you can upload the json file in the Query Editor below 2M only.

[image]

Based on the [statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-inputs#stream-data-from-blob-storage) in the official document.

> For scenarios with large quantities of unstructured data to store in
>   the cloud, Azure Blob storage offers a cost-effective and scalable
>   solution. Data in Blob storage is usually considered data at rest;
>   however, blob data can be processed as a data stream by Stream
>   Analytics.

I suggest you storing large size json file into blob storage and it will be processed as data stream.

Comment: Thanks @Jay Gong.  will try adding the json file into blob storage.

Comment: @Antony Good,if it works,you could mark the answer for others' reference,thanks.

Comment: I confirm that it's a limitation of the testing experience. I'll ask the team to update the error message to make this clearer. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the large size json file into Blob storage and feeding as input to Stream analytics works. Thanks @Jay Gong